# Animate image out of view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, sdk, uiimageview

I want a button to trigger the following action. When clicked it's supposed to push my logo up and out of the view and remove it. When it's clicked once more it's supposed to do the reverse thing. Meaning the image is created and pushed down back into the view. I'm using storyboard to set up my interface. My issue is that I can't get the animation to trigger. Posting my code below:

In TableViewController.h

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController{

    BOOL status;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *animateLogo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender;
- (void)showHideView;

@end
```

In TableViewController.m

```
@synthesize animateLogo, button;

- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    status = YES;

}

- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender{
[self showHideView];
}

if(status){

    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:1.5
     delay:0
     options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
     animations:^{
         [animateLogo setFrame:CGRectOffset([animateLogo frame], 0, -animateLogo.frame.size.height)];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL completed) {}
    ];

    status = NO;
    [button setTitle:@"Show" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
else{

    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:1.5
     delay:0
     options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
     animations:^{
         [animateLogo setFrame:CGRectOffset([animateLogo frame], 0, animateLogo.frame.size.height)];
     }
     completion:^(BOOL completed) {}
    ];

    status = YES;
    [button setTitle:@"Hide" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

}
```

EDIT:

The animation is working if I programmatically code the UIImageView. So the issue is with the storyboard somehow. I prefer to get this working with storyboard so I can get a better overlook on the layout.

```
UIImage *test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
    animateLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:test];
    [self.view addSubview:animateLogo];
    [animateLogo setFrame:CGRectOffset([animateLogo frame], 0, animateLogo.frame.size.height)];
```

Comment: Is `showHideView` ever called?

Comment: Yes, when I press the button.
- (IBAction)onClick:(id)sender {
    [self showHideView];
}

Comment: the block-based animations are strongly recommended in iOS4+...

Comment: Is the method actually called, i.e. did you confirm by setting a breakpoint or doing some logging? 2) Have you checked within that method if animateLogo is nil?

Comment: Yeah, it's called. Did a NSLog on animateLogo and it's a UIImageView, so it's not nil.

Comment: Changed to block-based animation as well but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem sovled. I used a different approach were I animated the UIView instead of the UIImageView. I's now working like a charm.